# Best javascript/ts approach for finding time till the next [day of week],[HH:mm]

Tags: javascript, datetime, typescript

I have been tasked with creating a clientside countdown timer for a list of records.  Each record has a value like I specified in the title (Example: Tuesday,05:00).  I need to show a running countdown on each row in an Angular 4 application so that if the current time was the day before at 02:30, the value would display as '1d 2h 30m'.  I am currently having a total block on how to get started and would appreciate any feedback for turning the next instance of 'Tuesday,05:00' into a usable date/time value to work with.

Comment: Take a look at http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

[MomentJs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) + [coundown plugin](https://github.com/icambron/moment-countdown) + (optionaly natives support for momentjs)

As simple as 1 liner:

```
console.log(moment("1982-5-25").countdown().toString());
```

For non-english find your desired moment locale.

There couldn't be possibly a simpler and more quality solution that one can write in the 5 min time it takes you to setup this.